# SVG text tag: show title on mouseover?

Tags: html, svg

I have an SVG text element that is split over multiple lines, like this:

```
<text class="label" text-anchor="middle">
<tspan x="0" y="0" dx="0" dy="0em">Managing</tspan>
<tspan x="0" y="0" dx="0" dy="1em">director or...</tspan>
</text>
```

I'd like a longer phrase, "Managing director or president", to display when I mouse over the text.

Is there a simple way I can do this, using a title attribute or similar? I tried adding a `title` attribute to both the `text` and `tspan` tags, but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<text class="label" text-anchor="middle">
  <tspan x="0" y="0" dx="0" dy="0em">Managing</tspan>
  <tspan x="0" y="0" dx="0" dy="1em">director or...</tspan>
  <title>Managing director or president</title>
</text>
```

SVG has its own set of tags. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title)